# How to conect wi-fi network without using GUI?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, fedora, wifi

I'm using Ubuntu Server 14.04, but I want to connect wi-fi network without using GUI?

Exists an software for that?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:fedora]?

Comment: I want to know is this software working in RHEL.

Comment: That is not clear from the question at all. Additionally, Fedora is the upstream for RHEL, but is not RHEL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294257/connect-to-wifi-network-through-ubuntu-terminal) thread and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138472/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wpa-wifi-network-using-the-command-line) one pretty useful.

If your wifi network uses `WEP` encryption, then

```
# turn wireless card on:
ifconfig wlan0 # wlan0 is your wireless interface

# connect to network
iwconfig wlan0 essid <name> key <password>
    # Here
    # <name> -- your access point name
    # <password> -- your password

# Then obtain IP address:
dhclient wlan0
```

If your network uses `WPA` encryption then you need `wpa-supplicant` for that:

- edit `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` with your favorite editor putting your ssid and password there:

  ```
  network={
      ssid="ssid_name"
      psk="password"
  }
  ```
- run `wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext && dhclient wlan0` where `wlan0` is your wireless interface. The last command is actually two commands, and you need to run both as root (system administrator). So `sudo wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext && sudo dhclient wlan0` or divide them into two commands around `&&`

For more information read the corresponding manpages.