# How to connect to Wi-Fi through wpa_supplicant, dhcpcd or nmcli?

Tags: networking, wifi, nmcli, funtoo

I use Funtoo Linux, clone of Gentoo with git instead of rsync and some bug-fixes (as I read).

I've installed LXDE desktop, NetworkManager but the applet does not connect when I type Wi-Fi password. So I need to connect in command line to continue installation and configuration.

Here it is the instruction: [How to conect wi-fi network without using GUI?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212501/how-to-conect-wi-fi-network-without-using-gui)

It does not work, giving this:

```
# ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
...
# wpa_passphrase WIFI222 20172017 > /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
# cat /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
network={
    ssid="WIFI222"
    #psk="20172017"
    psk=7.it975ot8o686f8fo86ff...
}

# wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext && dhclient wlan0
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument 
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument 

# wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf && dhclient wlan0
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant

# ping -c 3 www.stackexchange.com
ping: unknown host www.stackexchange.com
```

I have dhcpcd in rc-update, wlan0 is up, interface is not blocked. But this turn is unsuccessful too:

```
# rc-update show
       NetworkManager |      default                 
               binfmt | boot                         
             bootmisc | boot                         
                 dbus |      default                 
                devfs |                       sysinit
               dhcpcd |      default                 
                dmesg |                       sysinit
                 fsck | boot                         
             hostname | boot                         
              hwclock | boot                         
              keymaps | boot                         
            killprocs |              shutdown        
    kmod-static-nodes |                       sysinit
                local |      default                 
           localmount | boot                         
             loopback | boot                         
              modules | boot                         
             mount-ro |              shutdown        
                 mtab | boot                         
             netmount |      default                 
               procfs | boot                         
                 root | boot                         
            savecache |              shutdown        
                 sshd |      default                 
                 swap | boot                         
               sysctl | boot                         
                sysfs |                       sysinit
         termencoding | boot                         
                 udev |                       sysinit
              urandom | boot                         
                  xdm |      default   

localhost ~ # rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


localhost ~ # cat wpa
wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c<(wpa_passphrase 'WIFI222' '20172017') && dhcpcd wlan0

localhost ~ # ./wpa
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
sending commands to master dhcpcd process

localhost ~ # rc
 * WARNING: netmount will start when NetworkManager has started

localhost ~ # ./wpa
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
sending commands to master dhcpcd process
localhost ~ # ping -c 3 funtoo.org
ping: unknown host funtoo.org
```

Nmcli does not help:

```
# nmcli device wifi connect WIFI222 password 20172017
Error: Timeout 90 sec expired.
```

My other notebook funtoo+ xfce is connected to this network with nm-applet and I can see network has security WPA/WPA2. I just want to connect and install nm-applet on LXDE.

Please, what is not working ?

Comment: I don't know what wifi module do you have. Try this: `wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dnl80211`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly *what* goes wrong in your setup, but at least do the testing in steps. Trying to do everything at once doesn't help in figuring out where the problem is.

So.

1) Test that Wifi is working and you can see `WIFI222`:

```
# iw wlan0 scan
```

2) Add control interface to `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev

network={
    ssid="WIFI222"
    psk="your_wlan_key"
}
```

Adapt the path and group to your system, I don't know what Funtoo uses.

3) Start wpa_supplicant in an extra terminal window in foreground, so you can see messages, and uses the `nl80211` driver (nearly all modern adapters use this, you didn't say what adapter you have ...).

```
wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dnl80211,wext
```

4) Use `wpa_cli` to see what's going on:

```
# wpa_cli list_networks
```

should show the networks from the config file,

```
# wpa_cli status
```

shows the current status, and

```
# wpa_cli help | less
```

shows you other commands.

If you see `wpa_state=COMPLETED`, then you can run `dhclient` and try to `ping`.